# PHP Solr PECL Extension installation

Tags: php, solr, installation, pear, pecl

I have installed pecl/solr using command,

```
pecl install solr
```

and pear using

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php go-pear.phar
```

**After Restart Apache**, i am still getting error

```
Fatal error: Class 'SolrClient' not found
```

on php code

```
 $client = new SolrClient($options);
```

Can any one please describe step by step installation of pecl/solr extension on Centos.

Answer (score 4):

Just to simplify the procedure:

## 1 Install extension using

```
pear install pecl/solr 
OR
pecl install -n solr
```

## 2 Add this extension to php ini file

```
echo "extension=solr.so" > /etc/<Your php ini path>/php.ini
```

## 3 Restart the server

```
Service httpd/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Both installation commands gives `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/solr"`. Any idea what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You'd wanna check if the Solr extension has been enabled:

```
php -m | egrep -i solr
```

If it's not, this should sort it out:

```
echo "extension=solr.so" > /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/solr.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

The installation methods I found on the web ask to add "extension=solr.so" directly to the php.ini file in use , which seems to throw the error you are getting .

You need to remove "extension=solr.so" from your php.ini file and create a new file called "solr.ini" in your php extensions folder -- most likely /etc/php.d and add "extension=solr.so" to that file .

Answer (score 1):

Please create `solr.ini` file in  `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` and add "`extension=solr.so`" in that file.

or run this command in terminal

```
sudo echo `"extension=solr.so" > /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini`
```

and restart apache using the below command

```
sudo etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Note the sudo echo won't work, as the shell does output redirection not sudo or echo; `echo "extension=solr.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini` will work