# Fatal error: Class 'SolrClient' not found On Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0

Tags: php, solr, ubuntu-16.04

I can not solve this error message. I came across google and follow many forum answers and unable fix it.

[Fatal error: Class 'SolrClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959330/fatal-error-class-solrclient-not-found)

[PHP Solr PECL Extension installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750343/php-solr-pecl-extension-installation)

PS: 1/ I change the path

```
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

instead of

```
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

2/ Also I have verified the php.ini (solr extension appended) and solr.ini file creation.

Greatly appreciated your help!

Comment: solr version  6.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely no problem with the linked answers. But me(in ubuntu 16.04), it was required re-install the `libcurl-dev`, `libxml2` and `libxml2-dev`modules.

And,

Append `extension=solr.so` into `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` files.

Then run these 2 commands,

```
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/solr.ini
```

At last, restart the apache2. It is working...